# Percy Jackson fanfic where he is brought back from the dead as long as his friends get over it

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, percy-jackson

So, I've read a Percy Jackson fan fiction some time ago (on Wattpad).

Basically, Percy kind of died, but one of the goddesses (pretty sure it's Hera or 'Dite) gives him a second chance. She writes a letter for the half bloods and gives them two months to get over his death and to stop blaming themselves or Percy will really die.

Percy is able to interact with objects that have his name on them or pictures that have his face on them.

They manage to get over it (although Jason takes the longest to manage) and Percy gets turned human again.

And I'm pretty sure it's a Jercy pairing (Jason/Percy).

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fan-fiction-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1 for some tips on how you might add more details to your question.

Comment: If someone does post the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].